# Where did the term "doggone it" come from?

Tags: etymology, idioms, minced-oaths

Where did the term "doggone it" come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=doggone&searchmode=none):

> **doggone** 
>   1851, Amer.Eng., a "fantastic perversion of god-damned" [Weekley]. But Mencken favors the theory that it is "a blend form of *dog on it*; in fact it is still often used with *it* following. It is thus a brother to the old English phrase, 'a pox upon it,' but is considerably more decorous."

Others have it derived from the Scottish *dagone*, or "gone to the dogs," but there's a bit of [debate](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=&p=30864#p30864) about that.

From my own search, I found several pre-1851 uses. It looks like it may have first appeared in print in a British publication, albeit of an American vernacular dialog, in *[Adventures in Mexico and the Rocky Mountains](http://books.google.com/books?id=YX1NAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=snippet&q=goddam&f=false)* by British explorer [George Ruxton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Ruxton), 1847 (date [check](http://books.google.com/books?id=YX1NAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=albemarle&f=false)):

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=YX1NAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=snippet&q=goddam&f=false]

It subsequently appeard three times in 1848 in *[Blackwood's Edinburgh Magazine](http://books.google.com/books?id=wMae0jbOslQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=dog-gone&f=false)*, in articles written by Ruxton while living in America.

Comment: I think given related oaths such as *dang*, *dagnab it*, *dratted*, *tarnation*, etc., we can safely take it they're all basically eupemistic / bowlderised variations on **[god-]damned**.

Comment: "dog on it"... my first thought was "and what are dogs infamous for?  Exactly, shitting everywhere", which would make "dog on it" a synonym of "shit on it".  Which is probably not really English, but I'm prone to say it (to myself) as a not-really-translation of "Scheiss drauf"  ;-)  That's my story and I'm sticking to it (like that dog-stuff to a shoe ;-)

Comment: I think the association of dogs with shitting is a rather modern one; previous centuries didn't have quite the same fastidiousness as we have today.

Answer (score 5):

One possible route to *doggone* would be *God damn* -> *God darn* -> *doggarn* -> *doggone.* The earliest I could find a reference to *dog garn* is in the play *Ossawattomie Brown, or The Insurrection at Harper's Ferry,* by Mrs. J. C. Swayze (1859) [reprinted here](http://www.kancoll.org/khq/1937/37_1_edwards.htm). There are also a few Google books hit for *doggarn* in the 1870's and 1880's. I think this is fairly good evidence for the derivation through *doggarn*.

Answer (score 0):

As reported by the NOAD, the origin of the word is early 19th century, probably from *dog on it*, euphemism for *God damn it*.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps from the Scotch "dagone," gone to the dogs, or maybe an alteration of G*ddamn, 1851; doggoned, 1857.